# Debug Warning: String is not null terminated. Any idea what could it be?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I am concatenating several strings. When running the program it gives me a Debug Assertion Failed! message which says Expression: (L"String is not null terminated" && 0).

All strings seem to be NULL terminated, but I am not sure what else could it be. Any ideas?

I am including the code excerpt where it triggers the problem.

```
void foo(){
    ....
    char adj_command_string[COMMAND_SIZE];
    reconstructCommand(&command_parameters, adj_command_string);
    ....
}


void reconstructCommand(command* command_data, char* adjusted_string){

    char partial_string[COMMAND_SIZE];
    char string_rep[COMMAND_SIZE];

    if (command_data->g_code.new_value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "G%d ", command_data->g_code.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    // If position changed, include change in command.
    if (command_data->pos.X.value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "X%.4f ", command_data->pos.X.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    if (command_data->pos.Y.value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "Y%.4f ", command_data->pos.Y.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    if (command_data->pos.Z.value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "Z%.4f ", command_data->pos.Z.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    if (command_data->pos.A.value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "A%.4f ", command_data->pos.A.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    // If Feedrate originally included, include it in modified command
    if (command_data->feedrate.new_value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "F%.4f ", command_data->feedrate.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    // If spindle speed originally included, include it in modified command
    if (command_data->speed.new_value){
        sprintf_s(string_rep, COMMAND_SIZE, "S%.4f ", command_data->speed.value);
        strcat_s(partial_string, COMMAND_SIZE, string_rep);
    }

    adjusted_string = partial_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the source of the problem but:

```
adjusted_string = partial_string;
```

Will not copy the contents of `partial_string` into `adjusted_string`. Use `strcpy()` or some other similar mechanism and ensure that `adjusted_string` is null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to put more characters in the string than `COMMAND_SIZE` allows, leaving no space for the terminating zero. `COMMAND_SIZE` must be at least one greater than the maximum length the string could get, otherwise there won't be room to terminate the string.

Also:

```
adjusted_string = partial_string;
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. It changes the value of `adjusted_string` to point to `partial_string`, but then it throws away that value by returning. You probably want a `strcpy_s` call to copy the result.

Comment: I was just about to say this.

Comment: COMMAND_SIZE is 256 characters long. Certainly, I am not concatenating that many characters.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear as if `partial_string` is initialized, which it should be prior to using it as the target for `strcat_s`.

Something like this should maybe precede the `if` statements:

```
partial_string[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: That's it. strcat appends a string to an existing string but an uninitialized char array doesn't qualify as string since it doesnt necessarily have a null byte.

Answer (score 0):

further to @Schwartz:  to ensure always null-terminated...

```
char partial_string[COMMAND_SIZE+1];
partial_string[COMMAND_SIZE] = '\0';
```